# How do I replace Guava new MapMaker().softValues().makeMap() from Guava 17

Tags: java, guava

I was using Guava 17.0 with this

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Buffered> imageMap =
        new MapMaker().softValues().makeMap();
```

Just updated to Guava 27 and find that `softValues()` has been moved to `CacheBuilder`
so I can do

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().softValues()
```

but there is no `makeMap()` method so what do I replace with.

Comment: I'm guessing it's called `build`.

Comment: @marstran hmm, doesnt return a ConcurrentMap though

Comment: No, it returns a `Cache` which is threadsafe. It also has a `asMap` method which returns a `ConcurrentMap`.

Comment: @mastran okaya thx, i have CacheBuilder.newBuilder().softValues().build().asMap() but how to make it work for String/Buffered parameters rather than just Object, Object ?

Comment: Call `build` with type parameters: `CacheBuilder.newBuild().softValues().<String, Buffered> build().asMap()`.

Comment: @mastran thankyou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [MapMakerMigration on Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/MapMakerMigration):

> All caching related methods on `MapMaker` have been deprecated in favor
>   of similar methods in `CacheBuilder`, and are scheduled for upcoming
>   deletion. (...)
>
> Most `MapMaker` use cases should be migrated to either `CacheBuilder` or
>   `AtomicLongMap`. Specifically, cases when MapMaker is used to construct
>   maps with `AtomicLong` values should generally be migrated to
>   `AtomicLongMap`. Other cases where MapMaker caching functionality is
>   used (including all uses of `MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Function)`)
>   should be migrated to `CacheBuilder`.

So the question is: do you really need to use `ConcurrentMap` interface? If yes, use [`asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap--) view, which for non-computing maps should have same functionality:

> Returns a view of the entries stored in this cache as a thread-safe map. Modifications made to the map directly affect the cache.

In your case this would be:

```
private static final Cache<String, Buffered> IMAGE_CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .softValues()
    .build();
```

And then use `CACHE.asMap()` or use `.asMap()` with explicit type parameters for the field:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Buffered> IMAGE_MAP =
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .softValues()
        .<String, Buffered>build()
        .asMap();
```

Comment: thkx, but how do i get the parameter declaration correct (i.e String, Buffered). Im updating Guava to solve another issue so all i want to do is fix my code so it compilae and continues to work rather than investigating any further.

Comment: I've added an example.